# How do I detect display resolution change in Java?

Tags: java, awt

There does not seem to be such item in desktop properties, which I can list with this (from http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html):

```
 String propnames[] = (String[])Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty("win.propNames");
 System.out.println("Supported windows property names:");
 for(int i = 0; i < propnames.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(propnames[i]);
 }
```

I know I can use `sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment#addDisplayChangedListener` but I'd rather not explicitly use Sun classes.

Comment: the main issues is: why do you need to determine the resolution change, do you need it for some of the GC or all (on multi screen systems, you may not need it). You may do a compromise, overwrite some paint method + componentResized and check the resolution for the component you actually need to monitor there, i.e. poll the result of `component.getGraphicsConfiguration().getBounds()`. It's a native method but the overhead should not be a burden.

Comment: @bestsss: One use case is to avoid showing windows at out-of-bounds location. Our application saves the prior display location of all windows, and if your resolution changed (for example from a dual-monitor setup to Remote Desktop from another machine) we'll adjust the location (if necessary) to make sure you can see the window when you reopen it. `getGraphicsConfiguration()` can be very expensive so we don't want to call it every single time a window is displayed.

Comment: `getGraphicsConfiguration()` on awt is *not expensive*, it's just a lock w/ a field read.  FYI: during `show()` the lock is held. So I believe, the expensive part is just not true. Actually the lock is held very, very often.

Comment: Sorry I confused `getGraphicsConfiguration()` with `GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()`, which usually take 4 seconds on my dual-monitor machine. But for `getGraphicsConfiguration()` to return non-null, the window has to be displayed, so if it turns out the previous location is slightly out of bound, user may see the window move. It's not the end of the world, of course, and I'll weight it against using Sun proprietary change listener.

Comment: if you are concern about showing part: create a java.awt.Window (transparent, 1x1 pixel) and place it where your frame is supposed to be, get the GC and do the trick on the 1st load.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`Toolkit#getScreenSize()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize%28%29)?

```
Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
System.out.println(d.width);
System.out.println(d.height);
```

Comment: That's static, so I'd have to use a timer to call it periodically. I'm asking for a change listener API.

Comment: @Geoffrey I understand now what you are asking. I'll just leave my answer so you don't get duplicate wrong answer. I'll delete it eventually.

Comment: @Geoffrey [This post](http://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2010/Jul/msg00099.html) has a snippet but I think it's using the sun classes which you didn't want to use.

Comment: exactly, but thanks for the link anyway. Please keep the answer, I think it's useful. I just won't accept it :)